# C# graphics, paint, picturebox centering

Tags: c#, forms, graphics, paint, picturebox

Ok, so this is the problem: in C# forms I've created a new private void:

```
private void NewBtn(string Name, int x, int y)
```

Which has a purpose of creating a picturebox that imitates behavior of a button (don't ask why, I simply enjoy complicating things) and can be called as many times as I want.

```
Font btnFont = new Font("Tahoma", 16);
PictureBox S = new PictureBox();
S.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
S.Paint += new PaintEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = 
        System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Name, btnFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
});
Controls.Add(S);
```

Now, I am worried about part with Paint/Graphics (ignore rest of the code, I only gave some of it). I want to center the text that I write as "Name" in void when I call it "NewBtn(Name, x, y)". So, what should I put as

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(Name, btnFont, Brushes.Black, ThisX???, 0);
```

Suggestions?

Comment: As an aside, you should really name your methods better.  That method name indicates that a New Button may be created.  Method names should be descriptive.  In this case something like AddNewPictureBox

Comment: I am still working on that, thanks for suggestion ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var size = g.MeasureString(Name, btnFont);

e.Graphics.DrawString(Name, btnFont, Brushes.Black,
                      (S.Width - size.Width) / 2,
                      (S.Height - size.Height) / 2));
```

You can improve this by measuring the string only once, considering the font and text won't change for a specific Button/PictureBox.

And I would also suggest checking if `S.Size` is wider / taller than `size` and handling it, so graphics won't try to draw a string starting at negative coordinates.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! Also thanks for the other guy for trying, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3thd43b.aspx) [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21kdfbzs.aspx) that uses the [String.Drawing.StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.aspx) Option

```
StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
drawFormat.Alignment= StringAlignment.Center;
drawFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
```

You have two options here the first to use coordinates.

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(("Name", new Font("Arial", 16), Brushes.Black, 10, 10, drawFormat);
```

the second is to create a rectange like this:

```
 e.Graphics.DrawString("Name", new Font("Arial", 16), Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(0,0,this.Width,this.Height), drawFormat);
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but hey, why fix if it is working :) Will save it for later and try out, don't wanna miss anything, thank you.