# Saving common methods?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have numerous methods returning voids that I written for my program in C# forms which I use all the time. Since I need to use them on multiple forms, I figure there must be better way to save them in some Class, Data rather then copying them for every form individually... I am quite new at this so I am looking for advice. What to do?

Sample: I've created methods similar to these:

```
private void NewBtn(string nName, int locX, int locY)
private void NewPic(string nName, int locX, int locY, int SizX, int SizY, Image Img)
```

Now, instead of copying them in every form I want to write them in some other file and still be able to call them in any new form I add. Suggestions?

Comment: You can create a static class and define your functions in there. But I'm not really sure that's the best pattern. What do these functions *do*?

Comment: Side note: I have never heard methods returning `void` being called “voids”.

Comment: I am quite new at this as mentioned ( I think). These funcitons simply create pictureboxes with specific image, size and location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok everyone else has taken a shot at this I might as well too.
I think this answer has been suggested but maybe not explained clear enough.

add a new class to your project
in Visual C# you would go 
    Project -> add Class

Give your Class a name and click ADD

Normally I name this class Tools

then inside the Tools.cs file

EDITED:
I was looking at some of your other questions and I think I found the actual method you are trying to implement.  As someone had commented in that thread you really need to use better names, I have made changes to the method to hopefully simulate what you are going for.  For anyone trying to understand this please see [C# graphics, paint, picturebox centering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460124/c-sharp-graphics-paint-picturebox-centering)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNameSpace //Make sure this matches your projects namespace
{
    class Tools
    {
        //Because this is outside the form that is calling it, you cannot access
        //the actual form or panel where you wish to place the button(PictureBox)
        //so instead of returning void (which is nothing) we return the newly
        //created Button(PictureBox)



        public static PictureBox NewBtn(string nName, int locX, int locY)
        {
            Font btnFont = new Font("Tahoma", 16);
            PictureBox S = new PictureBox();
            //You need to specify a size for your pictureBox
            S.Width=100;
            S.Height=100;

            S.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(locX, locY);
            S.Paint += new PaintEventHandler((sender, e) =>
            {
                var size = g.MeasureString(Name, btnFont);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Name, btnFont, Brushes.Black,
                  (S.Width - size.Width) / 2,
                  (S.Height - size.Height) / 2));
            }
            return S;
         }
    }
}
```

Now in one of your forms

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(Tools.NewBtn("btn1",200,200));
```

or
    PictureBox myButton=Tools.NewBtn("btn1",200,200);

I did not compile this or test it in anyway, there may well be a typo, please let me know if there is something obvious so I can edit out the errors

Comment: This is actually most explaind solution till now, I am trying, will answer after

Comment: 'Since Project.Tools.NewBtn(string,int,int) returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression' -> is what I get when I try to type in "return returnbutton" :/

Comment: @AntonioTehSumtin As I explained in comments above, you have to change the void to Button because you need to return a button.  Look closer at the above code, notice the declaration public static Button NewBtn.  Then at the start of the method you declare a new Button, make the changes to that one, then send it back.  If the button needed to be based on an existing one, you can send a Button to the method  public static Button NewBtn(Button template, string name, int locX, int locY)

Comment: I made some changes to the above to reflect what I think you are going for, read the EDITED: statement  It seems you are after a picturebox not a button, so I changed the return type to a PictureBox

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I will test this and report my result :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make them [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx),

```
static class FormExtensions {
    public static void NewBtn(this Form form, string nName, int locX, int locY) { ... }
}
```

so they'll be callable from whatever `Form` as if they were declared in the form itself.

Or you can add them into a helper class (say `FormHelpers`) and add a parameter for the `Form` -- that is,

```
public void NewBtn(Form form, string nName, int locX, int locY) { ... }
```

and then use them by way of `FormHelpers.NewBtn(this, ...)`.

However, I'm actually questioning the use of these functions... What do they actually do? Create new `Button`s and `PictureBox`es, I imagine, but to what purpose?

Comment: Purpose is to create button and simply writting it's coordinates, size and image rather then writting 5-6 lines of code for every one of them since I m using many different buttons ^^

Answer (score 0):

What you could do would be to refactor them and put them in some sort of utility class. Since you will be adding these components to other controls, you could then refactor their signatures to something like:

```
public FormUtilClass
private void NewBtn(string nName, int locX, int locY, Control parentControl)
```

Once you do that, from your Form class, you do this:

```
public class MyForm : Form
...
FormUtilClass formUtil  = new FormUtilClass();
formUtil.NewBtwn("someName", 0, 0, this);
```

The assumption is that `NewBtn` will create a new button.

On the other hand, you could also create a class which extends a `Form` and contains these methods:

```
public class MyForm : Form
private void NewBtn(string nName, int locX, int locY)
{
     Button btn = new Button();
     ...
     this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

And then, when you create your own forms, you just extend from the latter class:

```
public class MyNewForm : MyForm
{
    this.NewButton("someName", 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm not managing to make it work, more explanation if you please?

Comment: @AntonioTehSumtin: I have edited my answer, I do not think I can be more clear than this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to create a super-class derived from Form, so you can derive all your other forms from it. Although it can be a bit tricky, it is a better architectural solution:

- Create a new class, let's say `public class CommonForm : Form`. Don't use `Add new form` but `Add new class` in order to make it a pure .cs file
- Implement your common methods in that class
- When creating new Forms, go to source code and manually add `: CommonForm` to derive them from this new class

Comment: Suggestions how to do it? ^^'

Answer (score 0):

one way is to inherit on a base form:

```
 public partial class BaseForm: Form
    {
private void NewBtn(string nName, int locX, int locY)
{
//Your Action
}
private void NewPic(string nName, int locX, int locY, int SizX, int SizY, Image Img)
{
//Your Action
}
}

public partial class SecondForm: BaseForm
    {
public SecondForm()
        {
NewPic(Parameters);
}
}
```

The Second way is to create a static class which contains the functions:

```
  public static class FunctionClass
        {
    private void NewBtn(string nName, int locX, int locY)
    {
    //Your Action
    }
    private void NewPic(string nName, int locX, int locY, int SizX, int SizY, Image Img)
    {
    //Your Action
    }
    }

public partial class SecondForm: Form
        {
    public SecondForm()
            {
   FunctionClass.NewBtn(Arguments);
    }
    }
```

Which one you choose rely on the method you want to implement. If you want to change the form (create buttons and so on) I would choose the inheritation.

Comment: So you suggest me to make multiple forms on same page?

Comment: @AntonioTehSumtin I would suggest to do the inheritation. So you can inheritate from a baseform and use these functions on each ne form. If you change the baseform these change will take place in the other forms too.